# Illustrator/PS images when sending to another computer?

Tags: photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I'm not sure how Photoshop works but when I receive an AI file from another computer I get an error regarding the images:

'Could not find the link file 'exampleimage.jpg'.

So I'm guessing the other person would have to send me the images separately?

Is this how Illustrator works?

I'm sure for Photoshop you don't have to do this?

Any info would be helpful.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Illustrator, if you go to menu File/Place, this will allow you to place other art files directly into your open illustrator document.  If someone gives you that illustrator file and they do not give the "placed" files as well, when you open the illustrator document it will give you that error message because it cannot locate those files that were placed.

While using the "place" command in Illustrator, if the "link" check box is selected, anytime a placed file into illustrator gets edited and saved outside of illustrator, the edits made to that placed file will update the changes in Adobe Illustrator.

Answer (score 0):

If the photos in their document are not embedded, you will need the images separately. Once you have the images, when you open the file on the new computer, you may need to manually associate the photos with each placeholder to make sure it renders properly.